# Why textFieldShouldBeginEditing method cannot be triggered?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I has declared in .h file

```
@interface TextFieldDemoViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

and implements this protocol method

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
NSLog(@"OK");
return NO;
}
```

Build and click a textfield, but nothing happen.
Did I miss something?

---

OK, I has resolved it: 
Connect textfield's Outlet 'delegate' to File's owner in IB

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer, and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect textfield's Outlet 'delegate' to File's owner in IB